# QuickBooks error adding custom fields to sub-customer/job QBFC

Tags: c#, quickbooks, qbfc

I am trying to add custom fields to job in quick books.

First I am creating customer and then adding custom fields by calling `AppendDataExtModRq`.

I see following error in log

> DataExtStorage::DoModify
>   Did not find Customer "Mayank Aggarwal". QuickBooks error message: Invalid argument. The specified record does not exist in the list.
>
> Status - 3140, Message - There is an invalid reference to QuickBooks Customer "Mayank Aggarwal" in the DataExt request.  QuickBooks error message: Invalid argument.  The specified record does not exist in the list.

But the customer/job does exist in quickbooks.

[image]

Here is the request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
   <QBXML>    
     <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
      <DataExtModRq requestID="0">
         <DataExtMod>
            <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
            <DataExtName>CLAIM #</DataExtName>
            <ListDataExtType>Customer</ListDataExtType>
            <ListObjRef>
               <FullName>Mayank Aggarwal</FullName>
            </ListObjRef>
            <DataExtValue>12345</DataExtValue>
         </DataExtMod>         
      </DataExtModRq>    
   </QBXMLMsgsRq> 
</QBXML>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you look up the customer by Id instead?  I haven't programmed for QB before, but it's possible that the string is not an exact match (hidden whitespace, non-breaking space, etc).  Just a thought.

Comment: Wow, so many downvotes? What is wrong with this question? I think it is a valid question for StackOverflow. I am not asking for code from anyone and have provided enough details. StackOverflow police strikes again.

Comment: Not sure. I just gave you an upvote, sorry I can't help more.

Comment: @pcdev Thanks for the upvote. I just don't understand why people just downvote for no reason at all, if they think there is something wrong here then why not just tell me and I'll fix it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @keith-palmer-jr can you please help? I am really stuck here.

Comment: @pcdev You are correct, I was able to do it with customer ID. Thanks for help. If you can put it as an answer then I can accept it.